# Iterate over two columns of a dataframe and replace null values based on condition of another column

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, missing-data

I need to iterate over 2 columns in a dataframe('bounces' and 'transactions') and replace the null values in 'bounes' based on the condition:
if bounces.null() and transactions>1 then replace the null value in bounces with 0
else if bounces.null() and transactions=0 then replace the null value in bounces with 1

Also, both the columns have float values. So I tried this:

```
df['bounces'].fillna(2,inplace=True)
df['bounces']=df['bounces'].astype(int)
df['transactions']=df['transactions'].astype(int)
bounces = df["bounces"].tolist()
transactions = df["transactions"].tolist()
for (a,b) in zip(transactions, bounces): 
    if a>0 and b==2:
        bounces[b]=0
    elif a==0 and b==2:
        bounces[b]=1
df['bounces']=bounces
```

But this isn't working
Please help. Thankyou in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"? Can you please [edit] your question and make the code a [mcve] please?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use mask tecnique [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.baseclass.html#numpy.ma.MaskedArray.mask) for a deep dive.
Mask is the fastest way to solve these kinds of problems.

```
# case 1  
mask1 = pd.isnull(df['bounces']) & df["transactions"]>1
# mask application
df['bounces'][mask1] = 0

# case2
mask1 = pd.isnull(df['bounces']) & df["transactions"]==1
# mask application
df['bounces'][mask1] = 1
```